# $wpdb prepare issue with mysql DATE_FORMAT

Tags: wpdb

Today, I have a issue in $wpdb.

I used

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( 
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(report_date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM table WHERE report_id = %d",
     $report_id 
   )
);
```

The above code not works because of %d in DATE_FORMAT. How i solved this issue in wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Codex page for the [WPDB class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks):

> [...] the `prepare` method [...] supports both a `sprintf()`-like and `vsprintf()`-like syntax.

Having a look at PHP's documentation for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

> ##Example 6
> ...

> ```
>    // notice the double %%, this prints a literal '%' character
> ```

So you can use

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( 
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(report_date, '%%d-%%m-%%Y') FROM table WHERE report_id = %d",
     $report_id 
   )
);
```

for your purposes.

Comment: Yea this works, I've done something similar using LIKE in a WHERE clause.